# How do you store a list of objects in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm looking for a way to store a list of objects within an array.

ex.

```cs
int[] array = {obj1, obj2, obj3};
```

And then be able to access information from the objects in the array, like:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(array[0].x);
```

I have been looking online and found a way to do it involving a list, but I didn't understand how to use it or how it worked.

Comment: Well, `MyObject[] array = new[] {obj1, obj2, obj3};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `IList` interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-5.0

```
IList<int> array = new List<int>()
{
    obj1, obj2, obj3

}
```

You can access the elements by `array.ElementAt(0).x`

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. This was so fast.

I would mark it as the answer, but you answered so fast I can't yet. :)

Comment: it should be List<myObject> array = new List<myObject>(), assume myObject.x is valid.

Comment: You mentioned `IList` then don't use it in your code. That, plus `IList` should generally be avoided in preference since `IReadOnlyList` was introduced.

Comment: `array.ElementAt(0).x` is also not a good suggestion. `array[0].x` is simpler and faster. Although the choice of name is not optimal (since array isn't actually an array).

Answer (score 1):

You have different possibilities to accomplish this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    ClassA[] array = { new ClassA(), new ClassA(), new ClassA()};
    
    for(var i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/
        Console.WriteLine(array[i].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
        
    foreach(var item in array)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    
    var enumerable = array.AsEnumerable();
    for(var i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=net-5.0
        Console.WriteLine(enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    
    // All these things also apply for the int[] array like in your question
    int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3};
    for(var i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array2[i]);
    }

    // Or use a List<T> instead
    var list = new List<ClassA>();
    list.Add(new ClassA());
    list.Add(new ClassA());
    list.Add(new ClassA());
    
    for(var i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Value);
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}";
}
```

Working example on [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eZpNzw)